# A few questions regarding IMAP via PHP

Tags: php, imap

I'm trying to figure out how to customize this piece of PHP code in such a way, so that I can set two specific conditions, based on the PHP error notices that I am receiving.

```
<?php

/* connect to yahoo */

$hostname = '{imap.mail.yahoo.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';

$username = 'user@yahoo.com';

$password = 'password';

$alerts = imap_alerts()



/* try to connect */

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to yahoo: ' . $alerts);

 if ( $inbox === false ) {

exit ("Can't connect: " . imap_last_error() ."\n");

}

else

{

echo"Logined:";

//do stuff

}


?>
```

What I wanna accomplish is:

1. Connect to the IMAP server.
2. Check if the user/password combo is correct, and if so, log me in ( I got that covered ).
3. If it isn't, I will just be greeted with an IMAP error stating "Too many login failures".
4. If it is, but I am trying to log in from a location that Yahoo doesn't recognize, that is, I have never logged in from there before, I will get the same error.
5. Depending on whether the user/pass combo is incorrect, or the location isn't recognized, redirect the user to either "page1" or "page2".

The imap_last_error returns the same error for both cases. The error alerts ( imap_alerts ), however, are different for both cases, and this is where I can differentiate between them.

How can I set it up so that when it attempts to log in, and it receives an error notice, containing a certain text string, it would just read that text string ( not displaying the errors at all ), and redirect to either "1" or "2"?

The redirect itself should not be a problem. The differentiation is what's tripping me up here. I would like the IMAP notice received to be dumped into a text file ( or, ideally, read directly ), and, depending on whether it contains "String A" or "String B", the next script action will be a redirect to either Page 1 or Page 2.

IMAP wrong user/pass combo notice:

Notice: Unknown: [AUTHORIZATIONFAILED] Incorrect username or password.

IMAP unknown location notice:

Notice: Unknown: [AUTHORIZATIONFAILED] Please verify your account at https://login.yahoo.com.

Answer (score -1):

To stop errors from showing use @ before the function in your case `@imap_open` after that use

```
imap_errors();
imap_alerts();
```

to get errors ex:

```
$errors = imap_errors();
for ($i=0; $i<count($errors); $i++) {
   echo "{$errors[$i]} <BR>\n";
}
```

Comment: Cheers. Will do that, but how do I instruct it to actually read what's contained in the imap_alerts array, so that the script can check for the existence of a specified string, and decide on the outcome?

Comment: @user2862063 added an example on the answer

Comment: Yes, I just saw it. That does indeed echo out the contents of the imap_alerts array, but I don't want that to be echoed - I want it to be passively read by the interpreter, checked for the presence of a certain text string ( in my case two of them ), and, depending on the presence of either string, activate an automatic redirect to a certain location.

Comment: I changed my code: 


    <?php

   
    /* Initialize connection */

    $inbox = @imap_open($hostname,$username,$password);
    $filename = "imap.txt";
    $errors = imap_errors();
    for ($i=0; $i<count($errors); $i++) {
    $file = fopen("$filename", "a");
    fputs($file, "$errors[$i]\r\n");
    fclose($file);

    $response = file_get_contents('$filename');
    if ($response == 'Incorrect username or password.') {

 echo 'Redirect to 1.'; }
  
    }

How do I make sure that, whatever's in "imap.txt", gets overwritten every time the script is run, and not just added to?

Comment: you are using adding mode in fopen use fopen("$filename", "w") instead to overwrite, take a look here http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fopen.php

Comment: Yup, got it. All done and working like a charm now, your help is much appreciated!